# How can I add fields such as company name, company website, etc to a django user form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, web-frameworks

How can I add fields like company name and website to the standard django user authentication form? I already have used their default fields for username, password, etc, but I'd love to add these fields as well. I know there are a couple of ways to do this, but what would you think is best?
I've looked at the django documentation on how to do this, but I'm still unclear on how exactly it should be done.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
-Ramsey

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to extend the user by creating OneToOneField:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,blank=True,null=True)
      phone = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
      location =  models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

and so on - your properties

Then, when you sign up new user you provide the request.user as argument:

```
 profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user,phone=phone,location='')
```

At this point your user's extra data is accessible as
user.profile.phone, user.profile.location and so on so you can use Profile model as an extension to user for your forms if needed.

In your Profile model if you need to access user's properties:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,blank=True,null=True)
      phone = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
      location =  models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

      @property
      def first_name(self):
         return self.user.first_name # this will give you user's property
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I'm still a bit confused on the last step.
Basically the idea is that there's a first view where you enter basic user information, and then the next view will have the profile form/mode. How do I tell the second form/webpage what user to choose from the list of potential users. Does that make sense? Is there a cookie or something that can be used to do this.Basically I want John to sign up on page one, and on page two, the form will know that username john has just registered, and that all the information he's about to enter is to be linked under john's account.
Thanks much.

Comment: You can always refer user from profile and profile from user - so the same way you access first name you can access rest of the user's properties (see the example).. If your profile (the wrapper) is p than it's either p.first_name or p.user.first_name